# Unable to invoke cucumber junit test from maven command line

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am trying to invoke my cucumber java tests from mvn command line and unable to do so for no reason why and using sure fire plugin to run it.

Here is my pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mystest.ui.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>mystest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>csp_ui_automation</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
      <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>30.1.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>6.10.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>6.10.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
    <plugins>
      <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
      <systemProperties>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
        </property>
      </systemProperties>
        <!--<parallel>methods</parallel>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>-->
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

[image]

And here is my runner class to invoke it by

> mvn clean test -Denv=QA -Dtest=RunCukesTest.java -DtestFailureIgnore=false

Unable to understand where I have missed the configuration and trying to get it running since yesterday

```html
package parallel;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import managers.FileReader;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

        features = "classpath:features",glue = "src/test/stepDefinations",
        plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
                    "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml","rerun:target/rerun.txt",
                    "json:target/CucumberTestReport.json",
                    "timeline:target/test-output-thread/",
                    "html:target/cucumber-report.html"}, //" "pretty" removed it
                tags="@QA", //Handled from CLI
        monochrome = false,
        publish = false
)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

Comment: Do you get any output from cucumber like a json or report file?

Comment: Yes, it has created the json result file where it shows, the test has been skipped.

Comment: I am just guessing.. You are passing a system variable `-Dtest=RunCukesTest.java` in command but not configured any property in `pom.xml` Or are you using this variable directly in code?

Comment: can you try cucumber option like this  >>>>>>>> mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @dummyTestVeh"

Answer (score 0):

you can use -- mvn clean install "-Dcucumber.options=--tags @yourtagName"